# migragted php script - now just getting question marks as page output

Tags: php

I migrated a php app form one server to another (5.2.4 to 5.2.17) and all the output i get from the application on the new server is questions marks:

????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

What I've noticed is that if I echo something from outside of function declarations I get the correct text, but if it's inside the function, I get the question mark:

```
if(!function_exists('nosql')){
echo "test";  // outputs correct
function nosql(){
echo "a new test"; // outputs "???????????????" to the page
```

Thanks in advance.

-K

Comment: First off, you're not closing your braces. You need to do that.

Comment: thanks, but that is just a snippet to show the behavior.  the problem isn't the braces, it's something else...

Comment: Show a hexdump of the relevant page output, not an excerpt. What's the page charset?

Comment: charset is utf-8.  Something I did notice that is interesting is that running the file from the command line shows the correct output....

Comment: Guys, I got it.  It is suphp causing problems.  Not sure what is wrong with the config yet, but running as a dso fixes the output.  Thanks for everyone's attention.

Answer (score 1):

Check the encoding of the file in question. Save it as UTF-8 w/o BOM.

It's the best guess I can give with the information you've provided. I can give you some more guesses if that is not the issue.